# Which tool can I use to automate chatbot testing?

Tags: windows, software-testing, chat

Currently we are working on a chatbot messenger which is integrated with Microsoft Teams. We need to perform automation testing on the chatbot messenger. What tool should we use for chatbot automation testing?. Please suggest few open source tools as well as paid tools.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what communication protocol you use, [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) might work.  This [article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-to-load-test-popular-chat-plugins-with-jmeter) discusses its potential use for chatbot testing.